# SVN Author issue

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have SlikSvn and TortoiseSVN installed(from previous developer on my machine). When I commit to Svn Server repo (I do it via Eclipse 'Team'), I can see in 'History' wrong (prev. dev. name). Ofcourse, I have my own, new, credentials(login, pwd) while connecting to Svn Server. So, which Svn version does Eclipse use? where I can change this 'Author' property?

I dont need to change Author for prev. commits, I need to change Author for future commits.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you authenticate with your own credentials and svn commit keep holding another name? So weird!

Comment: Look for `.subversion` folder and erase any credentials from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple` I found file with strange name 'c536d24fd4bac4a555f992747b2b508c' where I found `username` property.